# Python, error installing telepot after upgrading to python 3.11

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-3.11, telepot, domoticz

I use Domoticz on my Raspberry pi (3B+) and decided to update the system and Python to version 3.11.2. After the update, the Telgram bot script stopped working. It turned out that it does not invent the Telepot package. When I try to install this package, I get the following error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pip install telepot
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting telepot
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/telepot/telepot-12.7-py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Collecting urllib3>=1.9.1
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/urllib3/urllib3-1.26.15-py2.py3-none-any.whl (140 kB)
Collecting aiohttp>=3.0.0
  Using cached aiohttp-3.8.4.tar.gz (7.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [84 lines of output]
      *********************
      * Accelerated build *
      *********************
      running dist_info
      creating /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-78vfsexi/aiohttp.egg-info
      writing /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-78vfsexi/aiohttp.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-78vfsexi/aiohttp.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-78vfsexi/aiohttp.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-78vfsexi/aiohttp.egg-info/top_level.txt
      writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-78vfsexi/aiohttp.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest file '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-78vfsexi/aiohttp.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no files found matching 'aiohttp' anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.lib' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dll' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.a' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.obj' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'aiohttp/*.html'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
      adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
      writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-78vfsexi/aiohttp.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      creating '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-78vfsexi/aiohttp-3.8.4.dist-info'
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 149, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3l7whspa/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 377, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3l7whspa/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 335, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 54, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3l7whspa/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 108, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3l7whspa/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3l7whspa/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3l7whspa/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
 File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3l7whspa/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1221, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3l7whspa/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3l7whspa/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/command/dist_info.py", line 103, in run
          bdist_wheel = self.get_finalized_command('bdist_wheel')
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3l7whspa/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 304, in get_finalized_command
          cmd_obj = self.distribution.get_command_obj(command, create)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3l7whspa/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 860, in get_command_obj
          klass = self.get_command_class(command)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3l7whspa/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 966, in get_command_class
          self.cmdclass[command] = cmdclass = ep.load()
                                              ^^^^^^^^^
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 202, in load
          module = import_module(match.group('module'))
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3l7whspa/normal/lib/python3.11/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 28, in <module>
          from .macosx_libfile import calculate_macosx_platform_tag
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-3l7whspa/normal/lib/python3.11/site-packages/wheel/macosx_libfile.py", line 43, in <module>
          import ctypes
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/ctypes/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
          from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I was trying to install *aiohttp* when I noticed this problem:

`warning: no files found matching 'aiohttp' anywhere in distribution`

With no effect:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pip install python-aiohttp
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-aiohttp (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-aiohttp
```

I try to other stuff, but It doesn't help.

Comment: Side note: `sudo pip install` is almost always a terrible idea. Don't mix PyPI and system packages.

Comment: For your second question ([please don't ask multiple questions at once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/248627)), the package is simply called [`aiohttp`](https://pypi.org/project/aiohttp/).